# How to approach sketching sine and cosine graphs with transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, graphing-functions

Any tips or suggestions in sketching these graphs quickly, and in ONE go?

In exams, I don't want to spend ages re-drawing the original sine/cosine graph, one by one, following each new transformation.

Are there any methods that people have found useful when sketching these graphs?

currently what i do (very tedious)

1. First determine the period
2. Sketch the original shape finishing at the new period
3. Determine the amplitude and apply this to the basic shape
4. Apply the horizontal translation (add this to the original values on the x-axis)
5. Apply the vertical translation (apply this after the amplitude)

Does anyone have shortcut methods, or suggestions to this? I really need to improve my speed and drawing these graphs. Would love to know how others tackle these graphs quickly, or more efficiently.

Comment: I think the way to improve your speed is to do lots and lots of them. The more of them you do, the more patterns and shortcuts you'll work out for yourself.